# Difference between rotation methods?

Tags: android, canvas, camera

My question is in about `rotate` methods in `android.graphics.Camera`.In Docs,I saw these comments:

> public void **rotateX** (float deg) Since: API Level 1
>   Applies a rotation
>   transform around the X axis.

> public void **rotate** (float x, float y, float z)  Since: API Level 12
>   Applies a rotation transform around all three axis.

There is my question:What is difference between using **rotate** (float x, float y, float z) and a sequence of **rotate*** methods,for example difference between these two snippets A and B:
A)

```
camera.rotate (x, y, z);
```

B)

```
camera.rotateX (x);
camera.rotateY (y);
camera.rotateZ (z);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The importance lies in the order the rotations are applied in.

Consider for example, an aircraft flying forward which first rotates 90 degrees on its Z axis (*roll*) and then rotates 90 degrees on its X axis (*pitch*). The result is that the aircraft is now flying to the right with its right wing pointing downward. Now consider the operation in reverse order with a 90 degree pitch followed by a 90 degree roll. The aircraft is now flying up with its right wing pointing forward (*these results may vary depending on your coordinate system*).

camera.rotate provides a quick and easy function for applying all three rotations using one function. The reason for the remaining three rotation functions is to allow for situations in which the developer wants to apply one or more of the rotations in a specific order.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source in `frameworks/base/core/jni/android/graphics/Camera.cpp` there is no difference:

```
static void Camera_rotate(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jfloat x, jfloat y, jfloat z) {
    Sk3DView* v = (Sk3DView*)env->GetIntField(obj, gNativeInstanceFieldID);
    v->rotateX(SkFloatToScalar(x));
    v->rotateY(SkFloatToScalar(y));
    v->rotateZ(SkFloatToScalar(z));
}
```